# angularjs - template of directive isn't compiled in the right way

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

i have problem with angularjs

```
.directive('field', ['$routeParams', function($routeParams){
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            compile: function(tElement, tAttributes) {
                var template = '<input type="'+tAttributes.type+'" ng-model="form.'+tAttributes.ngModel+'" /> {{form.'+tAttributes.ngModel+'}}';
                tElement.replaceWith(template);
            }
        }
}])
```

here i got input value **empty** bat the 2nd

> {{form.'+tAttributes.ngModel+'}}

i got true value, !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compile is used for providing prelink/postlink which links template and scope together. So you would have to use it in "postLink" or directly in link. Here is modified example - http://jsbin.com/lidufusiga/1/edit?html,js,console,output to show you would have to use $compile on template and then link it to the scope.

```
.directive('field', function($compile){
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            compile: function(tElement, tAttributes) {         
               var template = '<input type="'+tAttributes.type+'" ng-model="form.'+tAttributes.ngModel+'" /> {{form.'+tAttributes.ngModel+'}}';

              console.log(template);

              return function(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
                iElement.replaceWith($compile(template)(scope));
              };
            }
        };
}
```

---

**But I wouldn't do that**, instead I would just provide template as function, where you can do what you are trying in the same way.

http://jsbin.com/korivokocu/edit?html,js,console,output

```
  .directive('field', function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            template: function(tElement, tAttributes) {
                var template = '<input type="'+tAttributes.type+'" ng-model="form.'+tAttributes.ngModel+'" /> {{form.'+tAttributes.ngModel+'}}';

              return template;
            }
        };
});
```

I would add one more oppinion. I wouldn't try to encapsulate fields like this, because you are not able to provide validations easily as you would when using inputs directly. Maybe you have  your reasons.